# Can anyone explain how session_start event count in GA4 is different from session metric?

Tags: session, google-analytics

I studied the definitions of session metric and session_start event in GA4 documents. it mentioned that every time a session starts a session_start event is counting, but comparing session metrics in reports and session_start event count I get two significantly different values. can anyone explain to me how these two are different?

Comment: You can refer to [this doc](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11986666#sessions&zippy=%2Cin-this-article) to understand the session difference in UA vs GA4

Comment: The question is not about UA vs GA4.

Answer (score 1):

The metrics are different.

When you select a period and ask to count sessions, every hit with a unique session id counts as a session.

When you do the same, but ask for session starts, only starts will count.

Basically, you should always see more sessions than starts. Rarely will you be able to see equal numbers there. Also, the difference should remain approximately the same number regardless of the time window size.

You can read [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9191807?hl=en) more on definitions.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I ran across this post looking for a similar explanation and want to pose an alternate theory.

In GA4, it's quite possible to have more session_start events than sessions, because GA4 does a better job of tracking across devices.

For example, we have a travel site. A user might start by looking on their phone for a vacation and then switch to desktop when booking. In this case we would register two session_start events, but only one session.

There's a great explanation of that here.

https://help.analyticsedge.com/article/misunderstood-metrics-sessions-in-google-analytics-4/